# How to get the changes immediately in textEdit widget in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I want to make a regex tester. There are two textEdit widgets in the dialog. The first one is used to input the regex, the second one is used to input the data. If the regex can match the data in second textEdit, the matched string will be highlighted.

But I do not want to add any buttons in the dialog, so how can I get the changes immediately in regex textEdit widget, so I can highlight the matched data in second one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to catch this using the [`textChanged` signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#textChanged).

Just connect that signal to a callback, and you are done:

```
def my_callback(widget, *args):
    # Do something with the widget

textedit_widget.textChanged.connect(my_callback)
```

Comment: what is the my_callback? I used the Qt Designer to draw the GUI, and connect the first widget's textEdit's textChanged() to the second's redo(), am I right?

Comment: It's your callback that does *something* when the text changes.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `QLineEdit`'s signals [`textChanged ( const QString & text )`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#textChanged) or, for example, [returnPressed ()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#returnPressed). You can simply connect this signals from either of this two QLineEdits to slot, where you process matching and do the highlighting